# How to create a profile after user registration with Rails3 & Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, devise, profile

I'm doing a simple user with profile application. User registers and
are automatically logged in. Works fine so far. Now, I'd like to
create a profile after a successful registration and redirect the user
to his/her profile.

I have a User model and controller. Devise also created the
registration controller. I installed the gem. I copied over the devise
files and I plan to override the create action.

First, whatever I edit in registrations_controller.rb nothing
changes.

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
 prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only =>
[ :new, :create, :cancel ]
 prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only =>
[:edit, :update, :destroy]
 include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers
```

Secondly, how to insert the profile creation step?

```
def create
   build_resource

   if resource.save
     if resource.active?
       set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up
       sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
     else
       set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason =>
resource.inactive_message.to_s
       expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
       redirect_to after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     end
   else
     clean_up_passwords(resource)
     render_with_scope :new
   end
 end
```

I was thinking to add

```
 current_user.create_profile under is resource.active?
```

How would you guys tackle that issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Please format your post and use <code> blocks for the snippets. That way it becomes very readable.

Coming to your problem:
Devise by default sign ins and redirects to application root_path, after registration.
If you wish to redirect to some other path you can specify it in a couple of ways.
One is to specify root_path for your devise reource. So in your case it will be

```
match '/user/profile/new' => 'profiles#new', :as => 'user_root'
```

This will redirect you to `profile#new` every time you login.
To prevent redirecting to `profile#new` each time you can add a before_filter on `profile#new` to check if profile exists and redirect to some other page, say dashboards, if profile exists.

Here is the link showing how to change redirect_path for devise:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: Hi Pravin, thanks. I will try out. Just need to pass the the user id parameter then.

Comment: I think you can do it with current_user

Comment: How should I update sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource) to 'user_root'